# Node.js can access default port, but can't access specific port

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

```
http.createServer(function(request, response){
  response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.write('Helloworld!');
  response.end();   
}).listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("server listen on port::: 3000");
});
```

Here above is a quite simple snippet run in **Ubuntu**.
I can access normally by default port(80), but can't access by a specific port. 
What I accessed is an external IP, not internal localhost.
I can get correct response via command line of "curl x.x.x.x:3000", but I just can't open it in web browsers. 
Anybody who can give a hint will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Check your firewall (iptables) and make sure you don't have port 3000 blocked.

Comment: or you are running rails already in that port.

Comment: Check your iptable or disabled it to just test it or http://canyouseeme.org/ check what is being blocked..

Comment: @slebetman no port can be used except default port, and the firewall was disabled.

Comment: @kc007, I can get correct response via command line "curl ipaddr:3000", but can not open in browser. really strange.

Comment: Where are you running that `curl`?

Comment: Only issue with 3000 port or all other port except 80??

Comment: @kc007, all other port except 80

Comment: Could you please show us output of netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN?? and please also show your iptables rules sudo iptables -L.

Comment: @slebetman, I running curl in both local machine & another linux machine, and it works well. but failed in all web browsers.

Comment: By **fail** do you mean the browser keeps reporting a 404 error?

Comment: @kc007, [netstat]   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8245/nodejs        [iptables]ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:3000

Comment: @slebetman, it reporting "can not connect to server". I can access normally via curl:~# curl 218.244.146.244:3000 
Helloworld!

Comment: I can see hello world from your root route..i just access from my browser http://218.244.146.244:3000/ and can see hello world as response..output is Helloworld!

Comment: Seems like your desk does not allow to query other ports than standard http. It's not an issue on your server

Comment: yes, I running curl from my local machine and get reporting:~ eyu$ curl 218.244.146.244:3000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 218.244.146.244 port 3000: Connection refused, so it might be another firewall refused my request.

Comment: Many thanks for all you guys comments. wish you all the best.

Answer (score 0):

A process is probably using the port.

`netstat -tulpn | grep 3000` will give you what process is using the port.

If none found, look into your iptables.

Edit: As suggest from comment, probably OP desk that restrict external request for non http ports. Simple iptable will do.

```
-A OUTPUT -d **dest_ip**/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

Replace **dest_ip** by your ip.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I checked netstat, and the port 3000 was listened well:0.0.0.0:3000

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've tired but still doesn't work, I think the problem is occurred with a strange firewall in my office.

Comment: Probably the case yeah, contact your sysadmin. You could also proxify your request as a temporary workaround.